# Having plaintext and ciphertext, how can I learn more about key/encryption?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis

I have an ***old*** work database that seems to have a simple encryption on the password. I have one users whose password is `7777` and the cipher text is `<<<<` (actual text).

Is it possible to learn any more about the encryption? Ultimately, I'd like to decrypt a few other fields in the database. I don't know what was used, but it seems very simple to me.

Sorry if this is confusing or lacking details, I'm out of my league here.

Comment: Do you have more plaintext/ciphertext pairs?

Comment: That is hex 37 changed to hex 3C.  A simple XOR of plain text byte with 0x0b would yield this.  But as mikeazo implied, we'll need more samples to know for sure.

Comment: Because adding 5 to the byte value would also yield this result.  More samples will help us to eliminate possibilities until we have only the valid one left.

Comment: Passwords are often "stored" as hashes in databases FYI in case it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to learn more about advanced cryptography, I highly recommend the book *Understanding Cryptography* by Christof Paar and Jan Pelzl. You can find it on the website for their book at http://www.crypto-textbook.com/

If you don't feel like reading, Paar recorded an entire semester's worth of lectures and posted them all on youtube for anyone to watch. That can be found at this link: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1usFRN4LCMcfIV7UjHNuQg

He goes into great detail about many of the top modern encryption techniques used by many companies. Anyways, I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I've got the inkling of a feeling that wlraider requires a top modern encryption technique here. I don't think this was a request for a generic education on cryptography - and if it was, it would be off topic.